# Problemas com o ng-required e ng-disable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aplicação-web, angularjs-scope, scope

Tenho uma aplicação web, onde uma pessoa pode inserir suas habilidades porém se há um bug que permite que ela insira habilidades em branco, então estou tentando usar o `ng-required` no `input` e o `ng-disable` no meu botão para que isso não ocorra, porém não está funcionando.

**View**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona da seguinte maneira, quando eu clico no botão adicionar meu *Controller* gera um novo `input` e ai é só escrever a habilidade e depois salvar.

**Código da View**

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="item in habilidades">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="removeHabilidade(item)">
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
            </button>
          </span>
          <form name="form">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-required="true" ng-model="item.nome">
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" ng-click="addHabilidade()">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        Adicionar
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Código da função** `addHabilidade`

```
$scope.addHabilidade = function() {
  $scope.habilidades.push({ nome: '' });
};
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o problema acontece quando coloco o `ng-disable` no botão Salvar.

**Botão Salvar**

```
<div class="panel-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="salvarHabilidades()" ng-show="!savingHabilidades" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    Salvar
  </button>
```

É como se o valor do `ng-required` não estivesse sendo passado para o botão salvar, apenas ficando na `div` dos *inputs*.

Deve ser algum problema com *scope* ou algo do tipo, porque se eu coloco o `ng-required="form.$invalid"` no botão de excluir(lixeirinhas) funciona, ficam desabilitados.

Comment: Não entendi direito, seria isso: http://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/Lvc0u55v/659/ ?

Comment: Sim, o objetivo é esse, mas não está funcionando o ng-disable. Pelo que parece o valor do $invalid que está sendo passado quando o ng-required for false não está chegando ao ng-disable do botão Salvar

Comment: Qual o `name` do seu form?

Comment: O name do meu FORM é " form ". Um nome bem genérico

Comment: quando tem apenas 1 funciona? Quando gera mais de 1 eles devem estar ficando com o mesmo name.  Vc já debugou para ver o valor que está no form.$invalid? coloca "{{form.$invalid}}" no seu html e veja como está ficando

Answer (score 2):

A solução que você procura passa pelo uso correto da diretiva `ngForm`.

Ela serve exatamente para você isolar o escopo de cada formulário e desabilitar o botão salvar de cada input individualmente.

Por exemplo no código abaixo:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in habilidades">
    <ng-form name="itemForm">
          <input type="text" name="nomeItem" ng-model="item.nome" required>
          <button ng-disabled="[CONDIÇÃO PARA DESABILITAR]">
              Salvar
          </button>
    <ng-form>
</div>
```

Onde está condição para desabilitar você pode usar várias expressões, como:

```
!itemForm.$valid
itemForm.$invalid
```

Onde `itemForm` é o a propriedade `name` do `ng-form`, ou seja, você verifica assim todas as validações de todos os *inputs* do formulário (nesse caso em especial é só o *required* de um `input`).

Ou é possível verificar a validade de um `input` específico assim:

```
!itemForm.nomeItem.$valid
itemForm.nomeItem.$invalid
```

Onde `nomeItem` é a propriedade `name` do `input` dentro do formulário `itemForm`.

Se ainda houver alguma dúvida, você pode pesquisar sobre validações de formulário nesses links:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController